# Parsing text file lines into numbers using std::iter::Iterator map

Tags: file, text, io, rust

I'm trying to read and parse a text file in Rust. Each line is a signed integer. I'm able to do it using `for line in lines` iteration but I'm unable to do it with a `iter().map(|l| ...)` one-liner. I'm getting a

```
expected `&core::result::Result<collections::string::String, std::io::error::Error>`,
found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
```

when I try to pattern match `Ok(s) => match s.parse()` but I'm unable to get to the bottom of what I am doing wrong. The whole example is below. The code on the bottom is the code that is producing the error.

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    // Create a path to the desired file
    let path = Path::new("input/numbers.txt");
    let display = path.display();

    // Open the path in read-only mode, returns `io::Result<File>`
    let file = match File::open(&path) {
        // The `description` method of `io::Error` returns a string that describes the error
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't open {}: {}", display, Error::description(&why)),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };

    // Collect all lines into a vector
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let lines: Vec<_> = reader.lines().collect();

    // Works.
    let mut nums = vec![];       
    for l in lines {
        println!("{:?}", l);
        let num = match l {
            Ok(s) => match s.parse() { 
                Ok(i) => i,
                Err(_) => 0
            },
            Err(_) => 0
        };
        nums.push(num);
    }

    // Doesn't work!       
    let nums: Vec<i64> = lines.iter().map(|l| match l {
        Ok(s) => match s.parse() {
            Ok(i) => i,
            Err(_) => 0
        },
        Err(_) => 0
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at the *complete* error message, which points to the error for us:

```
<anon>:5:9: 5:14 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&core::result::Result<&str, ()>`,
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected &-ptr,
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
<anon>:5         Ok(s) => match s.parse() {
                 ^~~~~
```

The compiler is expecting a `&Result`, but found a `Result`, and the issue is with the `Ok(s)` pattern. The type of `l` is a *reference* to a `Result` because you are using [`iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) - which returns [an iterator of references](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) to the items in the vector.

The shortest fix is to add a `&` to the pattern match for the closure variable:

```
fn main() {
    let lines: Vec<Result<_, ()>> = vec![Ok("1"), Ok("3"), Ok("5")];

    // HERE                                V 
    let nums: Vec<i64> = lines.iter().map(|&l| match l {
        Ok(s) => match s.parse() {
            Ok(i) => i,
            Err(_) => 0
        },
        Err(_) => 0
    }).collect();

    println!("{:?}", nums)
}
```

I also had to add [`collect`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) to go back to a `Vec`.

The other change you could make would be to *consume* the input vector using [`into_iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) and then iterate on each value in the vector:

```
// HERE                    V~~~~
let nums: Vec<i64> = lines.into_iter().map(|l| match l {
```

And for good measure, you could use [`ok`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok), [`and_then`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then), and [`unwrap_or`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) to say the same thing a bit more succinctly:

```
let nums: Vec<i64> = lines.into_iter().map(|l| {
    l.ok().and_then(|s| s.parse().ok()).unwrap_or(0)
}).collect();
```